# accessing values in arrays of objects

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I have a nested data structure / JSON, how can I access a specific value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/i-have-a-nested-data-structure-json-how-can-i-access-a-specific-value)

I am JavaScript beginner and have created the following array of objects in Javascript:

```
var values = [[{
       x_value: {
           x_axis: 1,
           y_axis: 1.8445
       },
       y_value: {
           x_axis: 1,
           y_axis: 1.2445
       },
       z_value: {
           x_axis: 1,
           y_axis: 1.1445
       }
   }],[{
       x_value: {
           x_axis: 2,
           y_axis: 1.35
       },
       y_value: {
           x_axis: 2,
           y_axis: 1.245
       },
       z_value: {
           x_axis: 22,
           y_axis: 1.345
       }
   }],[{
       x_value: {
           x_axis: 3,
           y_axis: 1.087
       },
       y_value: {
           x_axis: 3,
           y_axis: 1.125
       },
       z_value: {
           x_axis: 3,
           y_axis: 1.95
       }
   }]];
```

I would like to access the value of the x_axis of, say, y_value in values[0], what methods should I use? Thanks in advance

Comment: I would recommend to read the [MDN Javascript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide) to learn the basics, and/or http://eloquentjavascript.net/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you placed your objects in another array (holdings the objects only), then you need to make something like that to get the values:

```
var x_axis = values[0][0].y_value.x_axis,
    y_axis = values[0][0].y_value.y_axis;
```

Answer (score 1):

If at all possible, there's no good reason to wrap each object in another array, like you're doing:

```
 var yourCode = [[{}],[{}]];
 var better = [{},{}];
```

If you can change the data, just make sure that your script receives a single array, containing all objects (like the `var better` format above). 
As things now stand, you'll have to access the first index of the inner array, too:

```
var x = values[0][0].x_axis;
var y = values[0][0].y_axis;
```

If you change the format to fit what I sugested:

```
var x = values[0].x_axis;
```

Note that objects also support the square-bracket notation, which is very useful if the property-name/key is the value of a variable:

```
var getProp = 'x_axis';
console.log(values[0][0].getProp);//undefined, looks for property called getProp
console.log(values[0][0][getProp]);//returns value of x_axis property, variables value is used
```

Is enough... If you can, please use the second format, really. Not only does it require less typing, but however minor the overhead is, an array is not free. You're creating a second object (instanceof Array) that is completely irrelevant.